# How can I make this code run efficiently, currently it takes a very long time for it to run the code

Tags: vba, excel, loops

This workbook is used to track projects and I have this VBA code linked to a Form Control button, when I press the button it will run through and get information from all the project sheets and feed it to appropriate areas. I want to figure out how I can combine some of these loops where it reads through my entire work book. Here is my code :

```
Sub Run_ALL_InfoMacros()

'Module 5 = WIG Sheet1, for all information to be on one sheet

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ' Clear previous data on the All projects page
    .Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Range("A5") = "Project # :" Then
            x = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).row
            .Cells(x, "A").Value = ws.Name    'classifying number
            .Cells(x, "B").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$B$5"    'Project #
            .Cells(x, "C").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$A$1"    'Project Name
            .Cells(x, "D").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$B$8"    'Project Engineer
            .Cells(x, "E").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$B$6"    'Maximo Time Charge
            .Cells(x, "F").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$E$5"    'Material Forecast due date
            .Cells(x, "G").Formula = "=IF('" & ws.Name & "'!$E$11>0,'" & ws.Name & "'!$E$11,TEXT(,))"
            '.Cells(x, "G").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$E$11"    'Materials Forecast Actual
            .Cells(x, "H").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$F$11"    'Forecast success
            .Cells(x, "I").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$F$12" 'IFC Success
            .Cells(x, "J").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$E$6"    '30% Due
            '.Cells(x, "K").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$E$13"    '30% actual
            .Cells(x, "K").Formula = "=IF('" & ws.Name & "'!$E$13>0,'" & ws.Name & "'!$E$13,TEXT(,))"
            .Cells(x, "L").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$F$13"    '30% success
            .Cells(x, "M").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$E$7"    '60% due
            '.Cells(x, "N").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$E$14"    '60% actual
            .Cells(x, "N").Formula = "=IF('" & ws.Name & "'!$E$14>0,'" & ws.Name & "'!$E$14,TEXT(,))"
            .Cells(x, "O").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$F$14"    '60% Success
            .Cells(x, "P").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$E$8"    '90% due
            '.Cells(x, "Q").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$E$15"    '90% actual
            .Cells(x, "Q").Formula = "=IF('" & ws.Name & "'!$E$15>0,'" & ws.Name & "'!$E$15,TEXT(,))"
            .Cells(x, "R").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$F$15"    '90% success
            .Cells(x, "S").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$B$11"    'In-service Due
            '.Cells(x, "T").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$E$16"    'In-service actual
            .Cells(x, "T").Formula = "=IF('" & ws.Name & "'!$E$16>0,'" & ws.Name & "'!$E$16,TEXT(,))"
            .Cells(x, "U").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$F$16"    'In-service Success
            .Cells(x, "V").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$E$4"    'IFC Scheduled
            '.Cells(x, "W").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$E$12"    'IFC Actual
            .Cells(x, "W").Formula = "=IF('" & ws.Name & "'!$E$12>0,'" & ws.Name & "'!$E$12,TEXT(,))"
            .Cells(x, "X").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$B$15"    'Non Stores Items
            .Cells(x, "Y").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$B$16"    'Non Stores Items Ordered on time
            .Cells(x, "Z").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$A$17"    'Non Stores Items Success
            .Cells(x, "AA").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$B$17"    'Non Stores Items Percentage

        End If
    Next

End With

'Module 7 = WIG current & upcoming Projects, for all projects with NO Actual In-service Date Inputted


With Worksheets("Current & Upcoming Projects")
    ' Clear previous data on the All projects page
    .Rows("3:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Range("A5") = "Project # :" And ws.Range("E16") = "" Then
            x = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).row
            .Cells(x, "A").Value = ws.Name    'classifying number
            .Cells(x, "B").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$B$5"    'Project #
            .Cells(x, "C").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$A$1"    'Project Name
            .Cells(x, "D").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$B$8"    'Project Engineer
            .Cells(x, "E").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$B$11"    'In-service Due
            .Cells(x, "F").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$E$6"    '30% Due
            .Cells(x, "G").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$F$13"    '30% Success
            .Cells(x, "H").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$E$7"    '60% due
            .Cells(x, "I").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$F$14"    '60% Success
            .Cells(x, "J").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$E$8"    '90% due
            .Cells(x, "K").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$F$15"    '90% Success
            .Cells(x, "L").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$E$5"    'Material Forecast due date
            .Cells(x, "M").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$F$11"    'Materials Forecast Success
            .Cells(x, "N").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$B$15"    'Non Stores Items
            .Cells(x, "O").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$B$16"    'Non Stores Items Ordered on time
            .Cells(x, "P").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$A$17"    'Non Stores Items Success
        End If
    Next

End With

 'Module 2 = WIG Completed Project Info , For all the projects that are already in-service.

 With Worksheets("Completed Project Info")
    ' Clear previous data on the All projects page
    .Rows("3:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Range("A5") = "Project # :" And ws.Range("E16") >= Sheet6.Range("F1") Then
            x = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).row
            .Cells(x, "A").Value = ws.Name    'classifying number
            .Cells(x, "B").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$B$5"    'Project #
            .Cells(x, "C").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$A$1"    'Project Name
            .Cells(x, "D").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$B$8"    'Project Engineer
            .Cells(x, "E").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$B$11"    'In-service Due
            .Cells(x, "F").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$E$16"    'In-service Actual
            .Cells(x, "G").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$E$6"    '30% Due
            '.Cells(x, "H").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$E$13"    '30% actual
            .Cells(x, "H").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$F$13"    '30% Success
            .Cells(x, "I").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$E$7"    '60% due
            '.Cells(x, "J").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$E$14"    '60% actual
            .Cells(x, "J").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$F$14"    '60% Success
            .Cells(x, "K").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$E$8"    '90% due
            '.Cells(x, "L").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$E$15"    '90% actual
            .Cells(x, "L").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$F$15"    '90% Success
            .Cells(x, "M").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$E$5"    'Material Forecast due date
            '.Cells(x, "N").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$E$11"    'Materials Forecast Actual
            .Cells(x, "N").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$F$11"    'Materials Forecast Success
            .Cells(x, "O").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$B$15"    'Non Stores Items
            .Cells(x, "P").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$B$16"    'Non Stores Items Ordered on time

        End If
    Next

End With



'For Non-Stores Material

With Worksheets("Data Sheet")
    ' Clear previous data on the All projects page

    .Rows("141:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Range("A5") = "Project # :" Then
    Dim Z As Integer
    Z = 19

    Do While Not ws.Range("A" & Z) = "" And Not IsNull(ws.Range("A" & Z))
        x = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).row
        .Cells(x, "A").Value = ws.Name    'classifying number
        .Cells(x, "B").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$A$" & Z    'Non-stores material
        .Cells(x, "D").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$C$" & Z    'Lead Time
        .Cells(x, "F").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$E$" & Z    'Order By Date
        .Cells(x, "G").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$F$" & Z    'Date Ordered
        .Cells(x, "H").Formula = "='" & ws.Name & "'!$G$" & Z    'Goals Met
        Z = Z + 1
    Loop

        End If
    Next

End With




End Sub
```

Comment: Turn off automatic calculation for the duration of your code: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/5925/switch-off-functionality-during-macro-execution#t=201608152228470642729

Comment: You may also want to submit to [http://codereview.stackexchange.com/]

Comment: Where would I add the code to turn off the automatic calculation?

Comment: Usually at the begining.  Per http://www.cpearson.com/excel/optimize.htm, Screen Updating


You can turn off screen updating so that Excel does not update the screen image as your code executes.  This can greatly speed up your code.

Application.ScreenUpdating = FALSE

Be sure to restore the setting to True at the end of your macro.  Older version of Excel would automatically restore the setting; Excel97 does not.

Comment: @MaxFitzgerald The linked documentation tells you exactly how to do it... It asks you to copy-paste its code and has a comment telling you where to put your own code.

Comment: I completely agree with @mrbungle. Your post should be on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and not here. Also, go through the **entire** list of best practices in VBA coding in the newly created StackOverflow documentation. There are lots of good things to learn from. Finally, do as little as possible on the sheet. Do as much as possible in memory and don't access the sheet. So, I'd suggest moving the range to an array variable first. Edit the array variable and then paste it back to the sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is your whole code I'd suggest inserting this right after initializing your sub:

```
screenUpdateState = Application.ScreenUpdating

statusBarState = Application.DisplayStatusBar

calcState = Application.Calculation

eventsState = Application.EnableEvents

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Application.EnableEvents = False
```

At the very end of your code (above End Sub) reverse it:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = screenUpdateState

Application.DisplayStatusBar = statusBarState

Application.Calculation = calcState

Application.EnableEvents = eventsState
```

These settings should give you a nice boost in performance.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do - at the beginning of your code write

```
Call OnStart
```

At the end Write

```
Call OnEnd
```

Somewhere write the following:

```
Public Sub OnEnd()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

    Application.StatusBar = False

End Sub

Public Sub OnStart()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

End Sub
```